# Get string from variable lists in Bash

Tags: bash, variables

I have a file (`file.env`) similar to this:

```
kw_var1='string1'
kw_var2='string 2'
kw_var3='this is string 3'
kw_var4='does not matter'
kw_var5='maybe'

w_var1=qwert_1
w_var2=qwert_2
w_var3=qwert_3
w_var4=qwert_4
```

and I need to create a string `list_of_values` which contains the values of all variables that start with `kw_`, i.e.

```
$ echo -e $list_of_values
```

should output:

```
'string1' 'string 2' 'this is string 3' 'does not matter' 'maybe'
```

I tried to iterate over them, but cannot get this to work. My code:

```
list_of_values=$(for param in $(cat $file.env | grep "kw\_"); do echo $(echo -e '$'$param | cut -s -d '=' -f1); done)
```

but this is what I get:

```
 $kw_var1 $kw_var2 $kw_var3 $kw_var4 $kw_var5
```

Note that:

- the variable values will contain spaces;
- `list_of_values` will be used as an argument to another function

Any ideas with what is wrong?

UPDATE:

When doing the final echo I used:

```
$ echo -e $list_of_values | tr '\n' ' '
```

to get everything in one line.

Comment: Make sure to include a test case where one of the strings contains `=`, e.g. `kw_var6='this=that'`. When creating sample input/output always think about what might be hard for a script to get right and separators between sections of your string being included in one of the sub-sections is always one of those things.

Comment: @EdMorton: That is indeed excellent advice,I shall take note of it,  thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
/^kw_/ {
    sub(/[^=]+=/,"")
    str = str sep $0
    sep = " "
}
END {
    print str
}
```

e.g. note that it handles `this=that` in your desired output string correctly:

```
$ cat file
kw_var1='string1'
kw_var2='string 2'
kw_var3='this is string 3'
kw_var4='does not matter'
kw_var5='maybe'
kw_var6='this=that'

w_var1=qwert_1
w_var2=qwert_2
w_var3=qwert_3
w_var4=qwert_4

$ awk -f tst.awk file
'string1' 'string 2' 'this is string 3' 'does not matter' 'maybe' 'this=that'
```

---

Updated: given what you've now told us in comments, here's how I'd do it assuming you need to access individual values by their tags sometimes, otherwise you could use a regular array instead of associative:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

declare -A kw
declare -A w
while IFS= read -r line; do
    tag="${line%%=*}"
    val="${line#*=}"
    case "$tag" in
        kw* ) kw["$tag"]="$val" ;;
        w*  ) w["$tag"]="$val" ;;
        ?*  ) printf 'Error: unexpected contents: "%s"\n' "$line"; exit  1;;
    esac
done < file.env

printf '\nAll kw indices => values:\n'
for idx in "${!kw[@]}"; do
    printf '\t%s => %s\n' "$idx" "${kw[$idx]}"
done

printf '\nAll kw values passed to a function (printf) at once:\n'
printf '\t%s\n' "${kw[@]}"

printf '\nAll w indices => values:\n'
for idx in "${!w[@]}"; do
    printf '\t%s => %s\n' "$idx" "${w[$idx]}"
done

printf '\nAll w values passed to a function (printf) at once:\n'
printf '\t%s\n' "${w[@]}"
```

.

```
$ ./tst.sh

All kw indices => values:
        kw_var4 => does not matter
        kw_var5 => maybe
        kw_var6 => this=that
        kw_var1 => string1
        kw_var2 => string 2
        kw_var3 => this is string 3

All kw values passed to a function (printf) at once:
        does not matter
        maybe
        this=that
        string1
        string 2
        this is string 3

All w indices => values:
        w_var3 => qwert_3
        w_var2 => qwert_2
        w_var1 => qwert_1
        w_var4 => qwert_4

All w values passed to a function (printf) at once:
        qwert_3
        qwert_2
        qwert_1
        qwert_4
```

The above was run on this file.env without the redundant single quotes around the values, otherwise you'd just remove them in the script:

```
$ cat file.env
kw_var1=string1
kw_var2=string 2
kw_var3=this is string 3
kw_var4=does not matter
kw_var5=maybe
kw_var6=this=that

w_var1=qwert_1
w_var2=qwert_2
w_var3=qwert_3
w_var4=qwert_4
```

---

wrt [our discussion in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56496452/get-string-from-variable-lists-in-bash/56497627?noredirect=1#comment99665622_56497627) and using `printf '<%s>\n'` in place of `fitsort` which I don't know and don't have:

```
$ list[0]='foo bar'; list[1]='etc'

$ printf '<%s>\n' "${list[@]}"
<foo bar>
<etc>

$ printf '<%s>\n' $(printf '%s\n' "${list[@]}")
<foo>
<bar>
<etc>

$ printf '<%s>\n' "$(printf '%s\n' "${list[@]}")"
<foo bar
etc>
```

See how the first version correctly simply passes the contents of `list[]` to the fitsort-replacement command while the others pass the strings output by printf to it instead?

Comment: I love this approach, and it will very rarely matter that they do not come out in a specific order. If an order is needed, it isn't hard to add a bit of extra logic. It's clean, secure, and dependable.

Comment: OK, now I understand and understand better you approach, which ended up being the most adequate for may problem. Thank you for all the explanations and patience!

Answer (score 3):

**Trying your code**

I tried your command and get this as output :

```
$kw_var1
$kw_var2

$kw_var3



$kw_var4


$kw_var5
```

You had the wrong output because you chose the first field when you used `cut` instead of the second.

---

**Fixing cut command**

```
for param in $(cat test.txt | grep "kw\_"); do echo $(echo '$'$param | cut -s -d '=' -f2); done
```

Returns :

```
'string1'
'string
'this


'does

'maybe'
```

---

**Fixing IFS**

You used a `for in` loop but it does not iterate over newlines, it iterates over spaces. You need to change the IFS (Internal Field Separator) variable first :

```
IFS=$'\n'; for param in $(cat <file> | grep "kw\_"); do echo $(echo $param | cut -s -d '=' -f2); done
```

Output :

```
'string1'
'string 2'
'this is string 3'
'does not matter'
'maybe'
```

---

**Using printf**

To get the output on one line, you can use `printf` instead of `echo` :

```
for param in $(cat <file> | grep "kw\_"); do printf "$(echo $param | cut -s -d '=' -f2) "; done; printf "\n"
```

Output :

```
'string1' 'string 2' 'this is string 3' 'does not matter' 'maybe'
```

---

**Using while**

You could simplify the command and use a `while read` statement that iterates directly over lines :

```
cat <file> | grep "kw\_" | cut -d"=" -f2 | while read line; do printf "${line} "; done; printf "\n"
```

---

**Using awk**

Last but not least, you can use awk which radically simplifies your code:

```
awk -F"=" '/kw_/{printf "%s ", $2}END{print ""}' <file>
```

Output :

```
'string1' 'string 2' 'this is string 3' 'does not matter' 'maybe'
```

If the extra space at the end of the line is annoying, you can do this :

```
awk -F"=" '/kw_/{printf "%s%s", delim, $2; delim=" "}END{print ""}' <file>
```

Awk explained :

```
# Using = as delimiter
awk -F"=" '
    # If line contains kw_
    /kw_/{
        # Prints second field
        printf "%s%s", delim, $2;
        delim=" "
    }
    END{
        # Prints newline
        print ""
    }' <file>
```

---

**Final code**

```
list_of_values=$(awk -F"=" '/kw_/{printf "%s%s", delim, $2; delim=" "}END{print ""}' $file.env)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I needed. I also prefer the `awk` approach, much cleaner. Now I have a problem that for some reason the second function does not recognise the parameters, but that is a different problem.

Comment: and bravo for the explanatory text and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Make two arrays of your bunch of variables, then you can easily iterate over them like this

```
#!/bin/bash

kw=(
'string1'
'string 2'
'this is string 3'
'does not matter'
'maybe'
)

w=(
'qwert_1'
'qwert_2'
'qwert_3'
'qwert_4'
)

for i in {1..5}
do
    echo -n "\"${kw[$i]}\" "
done

echo

for i in {1..4}
do
    echo -n "\"${w[$i]}\" "
done

echo
```

Comment: Thank you, but that does not work for what I need, that would require me to change the script everytime I update the file with the kw list

Comment: Depending on how you use your file.env, you could put arrays in there directly

Answer (score 1):

I used dynamic references.

```
$: out="$( . file.env; for r in ${!kw_*}; do printf "'%s' " "${!r}"; done; echo )"
$: echo "$out"

'string1' 'string 2' 'this is string 3' 'does not matter' 'maybe'
```

Comment: that is awesome, and quite useful as I load the `file.env` file previously on the script, so I can just do `list_of_values=$(for r in ${!kw_*}; do printf "'%s' " "${!r}"; done; echo ))`

Comment: That does make it easier. :)

Comment: @jorgehumberto Hopefully you have total, rigorous control over the contents of `file.env` given how dangerous it'd be to do `. file.env` otherwise (e.g. if it was populated by some external tool and/or user input). It's very rare for that to be the right approach to doing anything (but of course this might be one of those cases where it is the right approach, idk).

Comment: @EdMorton: I use `file.env` to store the value for different parameters keywords that I then use to pass to two tools . (`dfits` and `fitsort` from https://www.eso.org/sci/software/eclipse/eug/eug/node8.html). There parameters will be loaded depending of the instrument we choose for the script.

Comment: @EdMorton: users do not have access to `file.env`, only to a symbolic link that links to the script.

Comment: OK then you shouldn't be doing `. file.env` but should instead be reading the values and passing them as properly quoted arguments. Is that why you're asking this current question? To create separate argument lists for the tools? If you ask a new question with a [mcve] showing what you want to do with the contents of this file then we can help you.

Comment: @EdMorton: Yes, my script is to be used with different instruments to extract header data from `fits` observations. For each parameter I need to pass to `fitsort`, the keyword is different according to the instrument. As such, depending on the instrument, the script will read a different `file.env`to load the variables from.

Comment: you just said the key thing - to be secure and robust your script should be **reading** a `file.env`, not blindly executing it. Like I say, post a new question if you'd like help.

Comment: And consider John Goofy's idea of using arrays (possibly associative) in your vars file instead of parallel names.

Comment: FWIW I updated my answer to show how I'd really tackle this given what we know now.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt uses a few practices that aren't recommended, and contains a few syntax errors:

- You use `$file.env`, but it should be just `file.env`
- Don't use `for` to read lines from a file (see [this article](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor))
- `echo $(cmd)` is the same as just `cmd` plus globbing and word splitting, which often isn't what you want
- `echo -e '$'$param` is going to print a literal `$` sign
- `cut -f1` is selecting the first field, but you want the second one

This is a solution "in the spirit" of what you tried, but using just Bash:

```
list=$(
    while IFS='=' read -r key val; do
        [[ $key == kw_* ]] && printf '%s ' "$val"
    done < file.env
)
list=${list% }   # Remove trailing blank
```

If you deal with strings containing spaces, though, it's generally advisable to use an array instead. Since `file.env` is valid Bash, we can source the lines we're interested in and then build an array with the values of all the `kw_` variables:

```
source <(grep '^kw_' file.env)
declare -n var
for var in "${!kw_@}"; do list+=("$var"); done
```

The array now contains one string per element, without the literal single quotes:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${list[@]}"
string1
string 2
this is string 3
does not matter
maybe
```

`declare -n` sets `var` to a nameref: it is treated as if it actually were the variable whose name it holds. This requires Bash 4.3 or newer.

Comment: wrt `echo $(cmd) is the same as just cmd` - no, it's not. The former will compress all white space in `cmd` output, may interpret escape sequences depending on the version of echo you're running, and will do globbing and filename expansion.

Comment: @EdMorton "The same or worse"?

Comment: I'd just go with `worse` BUT I guess it depends what the OP wants to do. If he WANTS to do globbing, etc. then it's better. So all you can really say with certainty is it's different :-)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, the `while` suggestion is particularly useful. Regarding the single quotes, I need to keep them as I will pass the values to a function as arguments. Without the quotes, the function will assume each word is an argument.

Comment: @jorgehumberto no it won't, you can see in Benjamin's `printf` that's not what happens.

Comment: @EdMorton: I am sorry, I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: You said `Regarding the single quotes, I need to keep them as I will pass the values to a function as arguments. Without the quotes, the function will assume each word is an argument.` and I'm saying that that's not true and you can see from `printf '%s\n' "${list[@]}"` in Benjamins answer where every element in `list[]` is not surrounded by single quotes and still is not processed by `printf` one word at a time that I'm correct. Consider `printf` as the "function" in your statement.

Comment: @EdMorton: It is indeed strange, when I use `printf` the quotes are indeed not necessary, however with `fitsort`that is not the case. More strangely if I do `dfits *.fits | fitsort $(printf '%s\n' "${llist[@]}")`, the spaces are transformed into "wider spaces", similarly to what happens when I use `echo` without the `-e` switch...

Comment: ok, what is curious is that is I echo that command and pipe it to `bash` (`echo -e "dfits *.fits | fitsort $(printf '%s\n' "${list[@]}")" | bash `) it works...

Comment: Jorge - Why are you using `printf` on `list[]` first? That's converting all of the entries in list[] into a single string of space-separated words before `fitsort` is called with that as the list of arguments. Just do `dfits *.fits | fitsort "${list[@]}"` (assuming that's the right syntax for those commands, neither of which Ive ever heard of). I added some code at the end of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56497186/1745001) to demonstrate.